# FPDF Encoding Issues

Tags: php, fpdf

I've been using FPDF utility in order to export html output to pdf reoprt.
I'm successfully sending text and displaying it in the pdf file, but the problem comes up while trying to display real html structures- like tables and etc.In  this case it seems like the encoding is not working well.

I've been trying to come up with a solution, but haven't had a success so far.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "encoding" - character encoding for special chars or creating a table in FPDF form a HTML table?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert HTML to PDF in PHP you should have a look at [MPDF](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php). With FPDF you have to parse the HTML yourself, extracting paragraphs, formatting, images and tables and then need to call the FDPF functions for creating the elements in the PDF - you're basically rewriting MPDF functionality.